# Android TextView smooth scroll

Tags: android, textview, smooth-scrolling

In my app I have a scrollable TextView but scroll is not smooth like i.e. a ListView.

I'd like to have same scroll "effect" like listview (bouncing, acceleration, ...)

Here's my code:

```
sNotes.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
                    sNotes.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                            boolean isLarger;
                            isLarger = ((TextView) v).getLineCount()
                                    * ((TextView) v).getLineHeight() > v.getHeight();
                            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE
                                    && isLarger) {
                                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                                moveY = event.getY();
                                touchDown = false;

                            } else {
                                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                                    touchY = event.getY();
                                    touchDown = true;
                                }
                                else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                                    float uptouchy = event.getY();
                                    if (touchY == uptouchy) {
                                        expandNotes = false;
                                        myParent.expandNotes = false;
                                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: place your `TextView` inside `ScrollView`

Comment: I imagined, but I was hoping there was a solution with textview only.

Comment: no, `TextView` does not have any `Scroller` to make that fancy effects

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. If you like answer the question I'll accept it.

Comment: its fine that it worked